# How to add a transition when state changes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a calculation tools menu that I fetch from API. By default, 3 are displayed, but when I click the "Show More" button, all elements are listed. I want to add a transition during this listing.
Do you have a suggestion for this? Using a transition over CSS does not seems to work.

First of all, this is the code I created to open and close the menu and show 3 items by default:

```
 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(3);
 const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

  const showMoreItems = () => {
    visible === 3 ? setVisible(data.length) : setVisible(3);

    setShowMore(!showMore);
  };
```

JSX:

```
<div className="row">
              {data.slice(0, visible).map(item => (
                <div key={String(item.Id) + String(parse(item.Name))} className="col-lg-4 col-12">

                  <IconCard bucketName="calculate" item={item.calculate} />
                </div>
              ))}

              <div className="col-12 more-tool">
                <button className="button button-more" onClick={showMoreItems}>
                  {showMore ? (
                    <span>
                      <Icons.ArrowUp /> TÜM ARAÇLARI GİZLE
                    </span>
                  ) : (
                    <span>
                      TÜM ARAÇLARI GÖSTER <Icons.ArrowDown />{' '}
                    </span>
                  )}
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

How can I make this transition more beautiful? I want to transition but plain CSS didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I think rather than making slice on data, which actually manipulates dom, you can try adding all div and play on classes like applying `visible` class, and adding this class transition styles.

Comment: I haven't used but try [react-spring](https://www.react-spring.io/).

Comment: @shyammakwana.me thank you so much! i'll try react-transition-group and react-spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/).

In your case, you should use `TransitionGroup`.